# Will all custom Open Graph actions stop working on February 6th?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, custom-action

It still isn't 100% clear to me what the consequence of the February 6th changing are. Facebook is *clearly* saying [in their roadmap update](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013):

> We will no longer show Custom Open Graph actions that were published simply by a user consuming content. If you own one of these actions and it was previously approved, you will have received an email from us. Developers should stop publishing these actions as doing so will return an error starting February 6th. The only actions that can be published upon a user simply consuming content are built-in actions. For more info, see this blog post.

It is clear that custom actions *that publish automatically and silently* to a user's wall through Open Graph will have to use the built-in action types: Like, Follow, Listen, Read, 
Watch. But this is about *user consuming content*. What about all the other custom actions? I.e. my app is posting about users Learning an english language content unit. Will these continue to work, as they are not about "consuming content"?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this guideline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/#criteria).
It provides you some detailed information/scenarios about what is considered to be *content consumption*.
I assume your use of Open Graph Action(posting about users Learning an english language content unit) is not a part of content consumption and still allowed. Of course it also depends how and when you post, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the meantime, I googled the hell out of the topic and I'm _almost_ sure custom actions still work. And yes, I will review my custom actions to make sure they don't shoot too soon.